# How can I access a parent window from a child window after a child popup is opened in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I access a parent window from a child window after a child popup is opened?

Answer (score 3):

`window.opener`

Comment: var popup = window.open("http://www.google.com"); popup.opener == window; //alerts true

Comment: `window.opener` a is a way to access to parent window from child. In this example you already have accesss point to the child - `popup` variable (no need to use `popup.opener`, just `popup`).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut105.shtml

Fyi, there's generally no reason to do stuff like this for modern web devlopment. Popup is usually a bad word.